# Entity cannot load data from related class

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-core, ef-code-first, code-first

i have 3 class like that and i used code first entity on .net

```
public class PersonModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonID { get; set;  }
    public string FullName { get ; set ; }
    public string Phone { get ; set ; }
    public string Adress { get; set ; }
    public int NationalNumber { get ; set ; }
    public List<SpecialtyToPersonModel> SpecialtyToPerson { get ; set ; }
}
public class SpecialtyModel
{
    [Key]
    public int SpecialtyID { get; set; }
    public string SpecialtyName { get; set; }
    public List<SpecialtyToPersonModel> SpecialtyToPerson { get; set; }
}

public class SpecialtyToPersonModel{
    [Key]
    public int SpecialtyToPersonID { get ; set ; }
    public SpecialtyModel Specialty { get; set; }
    public PersonModel Person { get;set; }
}
```

when i need to use specialityToPersonModel like this

```
var db = new EntityContext();
            var aaa = db.SpecialtyToPersons;
            return aaa.ToList(); // so Simple !
```

or like this :

```
var db = new EntityContext();
            var aaa = db.SpecialtyToPersons
            .Include(x=>x.Specialty)
            .Include(x=>x.Person);
            return aaa.ToList();
```

, it throw me out with this error :

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOqjR.png)

```
An exception of type 'Npgsql.PostgresException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code: 'External component has thrown an exception.'
```

Comment: You should have an inner exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its my fault that make DB bad at first , its from db not code ...
i correct my code and run

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

and

```
dotnet ef database update
```

again and so on ... Ty Anyway ...

Answer (score 0):

So shouldn't SpecialtyToPersonModel look more like this

```
Public Class SpecialtyToPersonModel{
[Key]
Public int SpecialtyID { Get; Set; }
Public SpecialtyModel Specialty { Get; Set; }

Public int PersonID { Get; Set;  }
Public PersonModel Person { Get;Set; }
```

}